# How to reference swift app delegate in objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift, appdelegate, bridging-header

I am trying to reference swift app delegate in objective C view controller as I want to submit data placed in `NSMutableArray` to `core data`.

**I have imported**

```
#import "SPOTEVENT-EventNotificationApp-Bridging-Header.h"
#import "AppDelegate.swift"
```

in objective C view controller but whenever I am trying to create app delegate instance it gives the error

> "Unknown type name"

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    AppDelegate   *appDelegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
```

Comment: Thanks Uma Madhavi but what kind of import do i have to use on top in objective C.m file

Answer (score 2):

The `Bridging Header` allows you to use Objective-C code in Swift. You need to import the `Generated Interface Header` to use Swift code in Objective-C

In the **Build Settings** section of your **Target** look for the `Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name` setting. Its normally `<TargetName>-Swift.h`

[image]

Most normally you import into a `.m` file to see the Swift classes.

`#import "MyTarget-Swift.h"`

You might need import into `.h` if adopting Swift protocols in OC but that can introduce circular dependancies with the Bridging Header so show caution.

If the `AppDelegate` class still isn't showing up you might need to add `@objc` to the class declaration or examine if your class is using any Swift features that would prevent the export from happening. You can `Command-Click` the import statement to see the contents of the header which can be useful for debugging.

Comment: hey Warren i have changed Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name to  SPOTEVENT-EventNotificationAPP-Swift.h like you said and imported it in .m file it is still giving me error.

Comment: Why is it still giving me error do i need to import something in .h file too?

Comment: I didn't say anything about changing the value. I said to look at what the value is and use that. In saying that, it should still work. Are you looking at the TARGET ( not the PROJECT ). What happens when you Command-Click the import ? . Is the `AppDelegate` declaration present in the header ?

Comment: I am looking at the TARGET and it gives the error SPOTEVENT-EventNotificationAPP-Swift.h file not found

Answer (score 0):

Do this step to use swift file in objective-c file.

1)  `#Import "YourProjectName-swift.h" in Objective-C (.m) file`

2) Now create instance of AppDelegate like below.

`AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

**Note:**- you have to add bridging header in your project.

Comment: My folder and project name is SPOTEVENT-EventNotificationApp.I have mentioned it in ObjectiveC.m file like this  #import "SPOTEVENT-EventNotificationApp-swift.h"  but it is still  giving error.

Comment: Do i have to create instance of APPdelegate.swift in objective C.m file and i have already added bridging header to my project